# how can I preserve the word spacing on display inline-block element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to achieve the next animation
[image]

So I decided to split every single letter into an  element.
Then I displayed every  as a inline-block element to translate vertically them as in the example.
PROBLEM: When I displayed every span as a inline-block, the word spacing is not showing. How can I solve this?

Also, having more than one text to animate, I have some doubts about how to code the progressive delay on JS.

Thanks in advance

```js
$('.splitSpan').each(function (index) {
  var characters = $(this).text().split("");
    $this = $(this);
    $this.empty();
    $.each(characters, function (i, el) {
      $this.append('<span class="letter-' + i + '">' + el + '</span>');
    });
});
```

```css
.splitSpan span{
  display:inline-block;
}

@keyframes down {
  from {transform:translateY(4px);}
  to {transform:translateY(0px);}
}
@keyframes up {
  from {transform:translateY(-4px);}
  to {transform:translateY(0px);}
}

.splitSpan span:nth-child(even){
  animation-name: down;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  
}
.splitSpan span:nth-child(odd){
  animation-name: up;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="splitSpan">HELLO WORLD<p>

<p class="splitSpan">SECOND SENTENCE</p>
```

Comment: You could try putting a non-breaking space character into the empty spans: `<span class="letter-5">&nbsp;</span>`.

Comment: A simple CSS `white-space: preserve;` should fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Reyno [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76927374/how-can-i-preserve-the-word-spacing-on-display-inline-block-element#comment135613037_76927374), add `white-space-collapse: preserve`

```
.splitSpan span{
  display:inline-block;
  white-space-collapse: preserve;
}
```

You could use `animation-delay` for the zipper effect. This could probably be done in the JavaScript, but I'm not knowledgeable about JS.

```
.letter-1 {animation-delay: .1s !important}
.letter-2 {animation-delay: .2s !important}
.letter-3 {animation-delay: .3s !important}
.letter-4 {animation-delay: .4s !important}
.letter-5 {animation-delay: .5s !important}
.letter-6 {animation-delay: .6s !important}
.letter-7 {animation-delay: .7s !important}
.letter-8 {animation-delay: .8s !important}
.letter-9 {animation-delay: .9s !important}
.letter-10 {animation-delay: 1s !important}
.letter-11 {animation-delay: 1.1s !important}
.letter-12 {animation-delay: 1.2s !important}
.letter-13 {animation-delay: 1.3s !important}
.letter-14 {animation-delay: 1.4s !important}
.letter-15 {animation-delay: 1.5s !important}
```

You'll also need to position the text so that it is offset before the animation begins. To hold the position after the animation, add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. I reduced the declarations to the `animation` shortcut property.

```js
$('.splitSpan').each(function (index) {
  var characters = $(this).text().split("");
    $this = $(this);
    $this.empty();
    $.each(characters, function (i, el) {
      $this.append('<span class="letter-' + i + '">' + el + '</span>');
    });
});
```

```css
.splitSpan span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space-collapse: preserve;
}

@keyframes down {
  from {transform:translateY(0);}
  to {transform:translateY(4px);}
}
@keyframes up {
  from {transform:translateY(0);}
  to {transform:translateY(-4px);}
}

.splitSpan span:nth-child(even){
  top: -4px;
  animation: down 1s forwards;
}
.splitSpan span:nth-child(odd){
  bottom: -4px;
  animation: up 1s forwards;
}

.letter-1 {animation-delay: .1s !important}
.letter-2 {animation-delay: .2s !important}
.letter-3 {animation-delay: .3s !important}
.letter-4 {animation-delay: .4s !important}
.letter-5 {animation-delay: .5s !important}
.letter-6 {animation-delay: .6s !important}
.letter-7 {animation-delay: .7s !important}
.letter-8 {animation-delay: .8s !important}
.letter-9 {animation-delay: .9s !important}
.letter-10 {animation-delay: 1s !important}
.letter-11 {animation-delay: 1.1s !important}
.letter-12 {animation-delay: 1.2s !important}
.letter-13 {animation-delay: 1.3s !important}
.letter-14 {animation-delay: 1.4s !important}
.letter-15 {animation-delay: 1.5s !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="splitSpan">HELLO WORLD<p>

<p class="splitSpan second">SECOND SENTENCE</p>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks for the quick reply!! But concerning the progressive delay I want to achieve something more faithful to the example. As you can see in the example, every character has a delay which is gradually increasing. Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: @JavierVentureira you could specify the animation-delay and/or duration (which combination actually works, to get the exact result you want, I'll leave up to you) via inline style on those spans, and calculate the value based on `i` ...